# I have a SQL query and I want to convert it to linq

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a SQL query which I want to convert to Linq.

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT
    Calisanlar.CalisanId,
    CovidYakalanmaTarih, 
    CovidBitisTarih 
FROM
    Calisanlar 
INNER JOIN 
    Covids ON Calisanlar.CalisanId = Covids.CalisanId 
WHERE
    Calisanlar.CalisanId IN (SELECT TOP 10 CalisanId  
                             FROM Hastaliklar 
                             GROUP BY CalisanId 
                             ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY, CovidYakalanmaTarih, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 30
```

I wrote this C# code, but it doesn't work as expected because i didn't write "DATEDIFF(DAY, CovidYakalanmaTarih, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 30" linq version:

```
var query = context.Hastaliklar
                   .GroupBy(x => x.CalisanId)
                   .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
                   .Select(grp => grp.Key)
                   .Take(10)
                   .ToList();

var result = from hastalik in context.Hastaliklar
             join covid in context.Covids
                  on hastalik.CalisanId equals covid.CalisanId
             where query.Contains(hastalik.CalisanId) 
                   && EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(covid.CovidYakalanmaTarih, covid.CovidBitisTarih)
             select new SonBirAyCovidDto
                        {
                            CalisanId = covid.CalisanId,
                            CovidYakalanmaTarih = covid.CovidYakalanmaTarih,
                            CovidBitisTarih = covid.CovidBitisTarih
                        };
```

Comment: In what way does it not work as expected?

Comment: `EF.Functions.DateDiffDay` simulates your DATEDIFF, but you have nothing in your LINQ to simulate the `BETWEEN 0 AND 30`.

Comment: yes, I couldn't write the linq version of it anyway

Comment: i didn't write "DATEDIFF(DAY, CovidYakalanmaTarih, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 0 AND 30" linq version @StriplingWarrior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not direct translation to BETWEEN in EF Core, but you can make other condition. Also it is better to remove `ToList()` from first query, in this case you will have only one roundtrip to database.

```cs
var query = context.Hastaliklar
    .GroupBy(x => x.CalisanId)
    .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
    .Select(grp => grp.Key)
    .Take(10);

var result = 
    from hastalik in context.Hastaliklar
    join covid in context.Covids
        on hastalik.CalisanId equals covid.CalisanId
    where query.Contains(hastalik.CalisanId) 
        && covid.CovidYakalanmaTarih <= covid.CovidBitisTarih
        && EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(covid.CovidYakalanmaTarih, covid.CovidBitisTarih) <= 30
    select new SonBirAyCovidDto
    {
        CalisanId = covid.CalisanId,
        CovidYakalanmaTarih = covid.CovidYakalanmaTarih,
        CovidBitisTarih = covid.CovidBitisTarih
    };
```

Comment: "have to" may be a bit strong. With the ToList() there, it'll materialize the list of ten items in one round-trip, and then insert them as a `WHERE IN (...)` clause in the second query. So it'll probably still work with ToList(), but it's probably a good idea to put the whole thing in a single round-trip, like you're suggesting.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, good point, corrected.